# Could not find file error on server but working on local

Tags: file

we are working on a project in which the user create/upload document which we store on server, and now we created new user role for external users(now we have internal and external user), the below set of code use to store the document on server

```
string storagePath = GD.Utilities.StoragePath;
string destFileName = Path.Combine(storagePath, item.FileData);
if (item.base64 != null)
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(destFileName, Convert.FromBase64String(item.base64));
```

this same code is working fine on local and even on our production server when I deployed the same on our clients server we are getting the below error.

Error: could not find file 'D:\CISPL\Extras UAT\Storage\PR-2022_2023-1.pdf'

please note internal users are still able to create/upload document but only external user is not able to create or upload any document.

Comment: check whether folder `D:\CISPL\Extras UAT\Storage\` actually exists on server and web process has permissions to write to it